# github - how to go to beginning of commit history OR scroll faster

Tags: github

Is there a way to either scroll faster through the commit history OR go to the very beginning?

I don’t see an option, not even on desktop site.

I’m trying to figure out why a certain branch was made but that info is not in the README section because the README is not customized per branch.

[image: screenshot]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think github has this built in but there are a couple of ways using URLs.

With some trial and error using `page?` gets you to the beginning of the history fast: https://github.com/micropython/micropython/commits/master?page=242

This is less trial and error because you can enter nearly exact values: you know the current latest commit's hash and github says there's about 8450 commits so this one gets you to the first page: https://github.com/micropython/micropython/commits/master?after=cada971113e6db0cf9e0751e95dbe9217dd707b5+8420

There used to be a [tool for it](https://github.com/wong2/first-commit) but the site is dead now so only the code is left.

But anyway, I'm fairly sure you'd achieve your actual goal way (examining log searching for something) faster without github, by using git itself. Github is fine for hosting but it's not exactly a complete git user interface. On th other hand git log/blame/rev-list commands are built for that. E.g. first commit hash: `git rev-list --max-parents=0 HEAD`